# Getting counts of children in a relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have 2 tables, one is for **Ticketcategories**:

```
CAT_PK, CAT_FK, CAT_Name
```

Where `CAT_FK` points to another category in the table that acts as the parent category, and is null is the category has no parents.

and **tickets**:

```
TIC_PK,CAT_FK
```

Where CAT_FK points to the category that ticket falls under. A ticket can only have one category.

Getting a count of tickets by each category is easy, but what I need to do is get a count of tickets for a category, including all tickets that belong to children of that category.

So if a hierchy like this exists:

```
Stuff
>Blue Stuff
>Red Stuff
>Yellow Stuff
  >Yellow Spotted Stuff
```

Getting a count of tickets of Stuff also includes tickets under all child categories in the count.

I have been messing around with recursive CTE's as a solution, but i'm not sure if it is capable due to the nature of counts and groups:

```
With
TicketCTE (count,CAT_PK,CAT_FK_Parent, CAT_Description)
as
(
Select Count(*) as count,CAT_PK,CAT_FK_Parent, CAT_Description
from Tickets
JOIN TicketCategories
ON TIC_CAT_FK = CAT_PK
GROUP BY CAT_PK,CAT_FK_Parent,CAT_Description

union all

Select Count(*) as count,TicketCategories.CAT_PK,TicketCategories.CAT_FK_Parent, TicketCategories.CAT_Description
from Tickets
join TicketCategories
on TIC_CAT_FK = TicketCategories.CAT_PK
join TicketCTE
on TicketCategories.CAT_PK = TicketCTE.CAT_PK
GROUP BY TicketCategories.CAT_PK,TicketCategories.CAT_FK_Parent,TicketCategories.CAT_Description
)
Select TicketCTE.*
from TicketCTE
left join TicketCTE MgrCTE
on TicketCTE.CAT_FK_Parent = MgrCTE.CAT_PK
```

Not sure if this is even possible because of the error I get,

> GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

```
;WITH categorylevel AS (
    SELECT 
       CAT_PK, CAT_Name,CAT_PK AS TopC 
    FROM TicketCategories
    WHERE CAT_FK IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT C.CAT_PK, C.CAT_Name,C2.TopC AS TopC
    FROM TicketCategories C
    INNER JOIN categorylevel C2 ON C.CAT_FK = C2.CAT_PK
)
SELECT TopC, Count(*) FROM categorylevel JOIN  Tickets
ON TIC_CAT_FK = CAT_PK
GROUP BY TopC
```

<kbd>**[See Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8df906/1)**</kbd>

Comment: This is really close to what I'm trying to do!
Problem Is it's not inclusive when I try to narrow down what I'm looking for.

Say I want a count of category 5, which would include category 1, 2 and 3 (all children of category 5)

If I change
    WHERE CAT_FK IS NULL
to:
    WHERE CAT_FK = 5

Then I get a count of each child category, but not category 5 it's self

Comment: Nevermind, If I change it to CAT_PK = 5 instead it works! Wow, thanks a lot @DhruvJoshi